# Attack using Java reflection API java.lang.reflect.get* method

Tags: java, reflection

Is java code using `java.lang.reflect.get*` methods vulnerable to privilege escalation, if yes then how? Also is the below code vulnerable to privilege escalation attack?

```
A a = new A();

Field[] field = b.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for(Field f : field) {

  f.setAccessible(true);
  Object fval = f.get(b)
  if(fval!=null){
      a.set(f.getName(), fval);
     } 
}
```